# Apply color using VAO in jogl

Tags: colors, rendering, jogl, worldwind, vao

I am trying to color my polygons in jogl. I have stored the vertices in an array, an index array for the triangle order and a color array. The code is as follows, but the problem that I am facing is that the triangle are white, and not the color from the color buffer.

```
    float f[] = {1000,2000,-4000,-2000,-2000,-4000,2000,-2000,-4000,1000,-4000,-4000};
    FloatBuffer buffer = GLBuffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(12);
    this.coordCount = 12;
    buffer.put(f);
    buffer.rewind();

    int indx[] = {0,1,2,1,3,2};
    IntBuffer indxBuffer = GLBuffers.newDirectIntBuffer(6); //Total number of vertices
    this.indexCount = 6;
    indxBuffer.put(indx);
    indxBuffer.rewind();

    float color[] = {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0};
    FloatBuffer colorBuffer = GLBuffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(12);
    colorBuffer.put(color);
    colorBuffer.rewind();

    gl.glDisable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glFrontFace(GL.GL_CCW);

    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, buffer);
    gl.glColorPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, colorBuffer);

    gl.glDrawElements(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, this.indexCount, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indxBuffer);

    gl.glDisableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

I am doing this rendering on NASA world wind globe. But I don't think that should cause any problems. Can someone help me figure out the problem? I am stuck on this for a while.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution, Just had to enable color and material.

```
   gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
   gl.glColorMaterial(GL2.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL2.GL_DIFFUSE);
```